# LibGDX uploading assets for desktop/android error

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Cannot manage next problem: I have created project on LibGDX for android, ios and desktop.
I have next line of code in my Attets.java class:

```
image1= new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/image1.png"));
```

(I am storing my image1 in the Projectname-android/assets/data/image1.java .)

Unfortunately, in this case my android application works well, but descktop program won't launch and shows error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/image1.png
```

In other case, if I set the same line of code like that:

```
image1= new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Projectname-android/assets/data/image1.png"));
```

Then I just get error in my android application, but my desktop one works perfectly.
I am using Intellij IDEA, if it is important.
The question is very straightforward, how to make this work on both platforms? 
Thank you very much for help!

Comment: please post the class

Comment: Have you linked the assets source folder to your desktop project, so that the "assets" folder shows up in your main desktop project folder?

Comment: How to link source folder? Is it hard?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892964/managing-assets-between-desktop-and-device-version-in-libgdx) link describes how to link assets.