# LibGDX Particle Effect works on Desktop but not on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I've set up a small test project using gdx-setup.jar with the "Tools" extension enabled.

The purpose is to test the Particle Effects feature, and the app builds and runs fine when I build the Dekstop project, and I see the particles and everything's great.

However when I try to build the Android project the app it closes before it even finished loading and I get an error saying "Unfortunately, ParticleTest has stopped."

In the Eclipse LogCat window I get the following error:

com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: particle.png

I've tried manually copying particle.png out of the gdx-tools.jar file and putting it into the Android/assets folder, then changing the contents of the Particle Emitter file to point to /assets/particle.png but that hasn't had any effect.

What's the correct way to get particle emitters working in the Android project, given that they work in the Desktop project already?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892964/managing-assets-between-desktop-and-device-version-in-libgdx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion P.T. -- that link doesn't apply to this situation though. I'm specifically trying to use the Particle Emitter that is a part of the LibGDX "Tools" extension. The extension seems to be trying to use the particle.png file that is held internally in the gdx-tools.jar file even when I set the Particle Emitter's config file to use an image file in a different location.

Comment: I think it boils down to the same problem.  The exception says "particle.png" could not be found.  I think you can just add "particle.png" to your assets directory without changing anything else.  (There may be bugs somewhere else that you have to do this, but let's see if this unblocks you.)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried

Answer (score 0):

Have you found an answer?

I'm afraid Particle effects are not supported on Android via standard way (tools). I have the same problem as you and I found out that the "gdx-tools.jar" is missing from Android directory by default. So there is no chance that Android could know where is particle.png because it's located in that library.

[image]

Additionally on offical LibGdx wiki says that "tools" are not supported by HTML, IOS, Android.

[Check it out...](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#tools-gradle)

I belive there should be another way to import particles in Android project. At least non standard.

Comment: Yeah, if you put the particle.png file in the root of the assets folder it works. ie, you have the folder structure of /assets/data/ and normally you put stuff in the data folder, but if you put the particle.png file in the actual assets folder *beside* the data folder then the particle emitter picks it up and everything works :)

Comment: That worked for me too, could you please write it down as an answer? And thanks a lot ofc